# Trello Organization and Board Limitations

Tags: trello

I handle projects for several companies, I assume that I would set up an organization for each company and the boards would be the projects for each. Along these lines are there limitations on the number of organizations I can create, or on the number of boards under each organization?

Answer (score 2):

Unlimited.

From [this Trello blog article about Trello Gold](http://blog.trello.com/introducing-trello-gold-board-backgrounds-stickers-and-more/) regarding new features (see questions near bottom):

> You can still use Trello for free and enjoy unlimited boards,
>   organizations, cards, and no usage restrictions, with or without
>   Trello Gold. You can invite an unlimited number of people to your
>   boards and organizations for free.